# Is there a way to toggle the Do Not Disturb Button extension based off a Gnome Calendar description?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, automation, gnome-calendar

The [Do Not Disturb Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/964/do-not-disturb-button/) extension is set to toggle on a keyboard shortcut (super+q). Is there any way to toggle it based on if I have "mute" in the event description in Gnome Calendar?

I have my phone synced to the same CalDav calendar and I can mute my phone using Tasker and its "calendar entry" state, which looks for *mute* in the event description. Was curious if there's any way to do the same thing in Ubuntu.